# Inverse of negative entropy function on positive orthant

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

What is the inverse of the function $f: \mathbb{R}^{+}\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x \ln x$?

This is an invertible function on the domain mentioned above.

Comment: Check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be defined in terms of the Lambert W-function (the inverse image of $ze^z$), as 
$x \ln x = (\ln x)e^{\ln x}$, so $f^{-1}(y) = e^{W(y)} = \frac{y}{W(y)}$.

Answer (score 2):

The Lambert $W$-function satisfies

$$W(z)e^{W(z)}=z.$$

Now, let $F(z)=e^{W(z)}$.  Then $\log F(z)=W(z)$, hence $F(z)\log F(z)=z$.  That is, $F(z)$ gives an inverse function to $z \log z$.